# Php | Crop Image Without Stretching

Tags: php

How can I have images cropped instead of stretched with Php?

For instance, if I upload a 600, 100 image, I want it to crop it to 100x100, in the CENTER of the image. So 250px from the left.
Obviously these numbers would depend on the image the user uploads.

Here is my current code :

```
$width = imagesx($base64);
$height = imagesy($base64);

$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $base64,
    0, 0,
    0, 0,
    $newWidth, $newHeight,
    $width, $height);

imagejpeg($tmp, $path)
```

If I am not mistaken, this code would take a 600x100 image and stretch it down to a 100x100. Opposed to cropping.

Answer (score -2):

Please try to use [this code](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecrop.php#121792):

```
$new = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

$crop_width = imagesx($new);
$crop_height = imagesy($new);

$size = min($crop_width, $crop_height);

if($crop_width >= $crop_height) {
    $newx= ($crop_width-$crop_height)/2;
    $im2 = imagecrop($new, ['x' => $newx, 'y' => 0, 'width' => $size, 'height' => $size]);
}
else {
    $newy= ($crop_height-$crop_width)/2;
    $im2 = imagecrop($new, ['x' => 0, 'y' => $newy, 'width' => $size, 'height' => $size]);
}

imagejpeg($im2,$filename,90);
```

You need to set your values for `$uploadedfile`, `$crop_width`, `$crop_height` and `$filename` variables.